# Msmq .NET api MessageQueue.Send does not throw where expected

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I am fairly new to Msmq, and I am not understanding the way the transactions work.

So, say I have a transactional queue and I send a message to it without specifying any transaction the method does not throw and the message goes nowhere. The documentation says -

***'If you use this overload to send a message to a transactional queue, the message will be sent to the dead-letter queue'.***

However I couldn't see the message anywhere in the system queues.

This the code for reference -

```
  var path = @".\private$\transactionalQ";
  if (MessageQueue.Exists(path))
    MessageQueue.Delete(path);
  var q = MessageQueue.Create(path, false);

  q.Send("non transactional message");
```

I see a similar behaviour when sending transactional messages to a non-transactional queue.

I expected the method call to throw if I was doing something unexpected. Am I missing something?

Comment: MSMQ was designed to work when the destination is temporarily unreachable.  The message sits in the outgoing queue for a while before MSMQ gives up and moves it to the dead letter queue.  I forgot what the default timeout is but it is hours, not seconds.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, where can I see this outgoing queue, I don't see it from the compmgmt snapin.

Comment: There are no outgoing queues when sending locally.

Comment: Thanks. Curiouser and curiouser...so if I send a message to a local queue with  incompatible transaction mode between send and queue, is the message effectively lost?

Comment: To have messages end up in the Dead Letter Queue, you need to enable Negative Source Journaling. MSMQ discards messages on error if you don't say you want to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

Your going right but there is no any facility to differentiate Transitional message and non transitional message in MessageQueue.Send Method.
    **MessageQueue.Send(Object)** 
method is not overloaded for single parameter rather than Object (I mean any specialized Type) So the solution is you have to First Check Message is in Correct format or not then you have to pass it to queue.
Also there only one exception related with Send Method is  **MessageQueueException**  and which is generated due to invalid path which you provide and error occurred when accessing a Message Queuing API.
For more information you can go through [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.send(v=vs.110).aspx)
and also [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329510(v=vs.71).aspx) .